# Angular library routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-library

I try to set routing in my library.

I have in lib-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'autologin', component: AutoLoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class LibRoutingModule { }
```

And in lib.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    LibRoutingModule,
    ...
  ]
})
```

When I try to compile the lib I get the following error :

> ERROR: Error during template compile of 'LibRoutingModule'   Function
>   calls are not supported in decorators but 'RouterModule' was called.

I have tried to add

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
  }
```

like I saw in some threads like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23609 but it doesn"t work, I still have same error.

Any suggestion?
Many thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in case someone has same issue, seems to have something to do with ng-packagr, so following this :  https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1127, I've added

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
  }
```

In my tsconfig.json and this is working now.